# Why my VBA code exits immediately depending on the active sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I think this is more of an issue with excel options and stuff but I'm not sure.  A description of my code: It takes time series data written in the first 8-9 tabs in a worksheet (each tab is a different indicator), and displays it in a row so that instead of data being written like in a time series format (1-1-2000 to 1-1-2015 for each indicator) all indicators (with three lags as well as 7 forward lags for the GGR tab) are written for a given date in a row  Here is my code:

```
Sub stuff()

     Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, rng5 As Range, rng6 As Range, rng7 As Range, rng8 As Range
     Dim datenum As Long, Row As Integer, sorteddate As Variant, loc As Integer

     Row = 2

     For j = 2 To 53
         For i = 8 To 275
             If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value)) Then
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 8) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 9) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i - 2, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 10) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i - 3, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 29) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 30) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 31) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 2, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 32) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 3, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 33) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 4, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 34) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 5, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 35) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 6, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 36) = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i + 7, j).Value
                 datenum = Sheets("GGR").Cells(i, 1).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 1).Value = datenum
                 Set rng1 = Sheets("CPIC").Range("A1:A408")
                 sorteddate = rng1.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng1, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 2) = Sheets("CPIC").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 3) = Sheets("CPIC").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 4) = Sheets("CPIC").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng2 = Sheets("GBGT").Range("A1:A71")
                 sorteddate = rng2.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng2, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 5) = Sheets("GBGT").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 6) = Sheets("GBGT").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 7) = Sheets("GBGT").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng3 = Sheets("GFCF").Range("A5:A264")
                 sorteddate = rng3.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng3, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 11) = Sheets("GFCF").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("testsheet").Cells(1, 1).Value = loc
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 12).Value = Sheets("GFCF").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 13).Value = Sheets("GFCF").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng4 = Sheets("M1").Range("A1:A700")
                 sorteddate = rng4.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng4, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 14) = Sheets("M1").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 15) = Sheets("M1").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 16) = Sheets("M1").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng5 = Sheets("M2").Range("A1:A676")
                 sorteddate = rng5.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng5, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 17) = Sheets("M2").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 18) = Sheets("M2").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 19) = Sheets("M2").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng6 = Sheets("CSP").Range("A1:A264")
                 sorteddate = rng6.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng6, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 20) = Sheets("CSP").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 21) = Sheets("CSP").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 22) = Sheets("CSP").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng7 = Sheets("UNR").Range("A1:A272")
                 sorteddate = rng7.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng7, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 23) = Sheets("UNR").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 24) = Sheets("UNR").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 25) = Sheets("UNR").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value

                 Set rng8 = Sheets("MKT").Range("A1:A223")
                 sorteddate = rng8.Value
                 loc = BinarySearch(rng8, datenum)
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 26) = Sheets("MKT").Cells(loc, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 27) = Sheets("MKT").Cells(loc - 1, j).Value
                 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 28) = Sheets("MKT").Cells(loc - 2, j).Value
                 Row = Row + 1
             End If
         Next i
     Next j
End Sub


Function BinarySearch(rng As Range, searchValue As Long) As Integer

     'dimension these as long to avoid possible integer
     'overflow errors for large lists
     Dim curIndex As Long
     Dim firstIndex As Integer
     Dim lastIndex As Integer

     Dim nextMiddle As Long
     Dim strValue As Long
     Dim MyCell As Variant
     Dim i As Integer

     i = 0

     For Each MyCell In rng
         If MyCell < searchValue Then
             i = i + 1
         End If
     Next MyCell

     BinarySearch = i  

End Function
```

I understand my code is not the most efficient, I was coding quickly and am not the most knowledgeable in VBA.  I also tried binary search instead of linear search but I kept on getting bugs so I just used linear search as speed wasn't an issue.  Anyway, when I try to run my code, once in a while (ie every 20 tries) it runs and gives an error.  The error isn't what I'm concerned about.  However when I usually run it it doesn't run.  It takes me about 30 minutes to get the debugger to show me a runtime error.  When I press the run button on VBA, usually it just exits.  I tried step through, and it highlights the first line (sub stuff()) and then the code exits without going through the rest of the code.  I already tried allowing macros in excel.  I have run other code simple 1 line print statements and that works.  I also tried copy and pasting it into a different excel and that made no difference.

Comment: Sorry apparently I'm terrible at formating for stack overflow (my first post although I visit the site often)

This is all part of the code:

Sub stuff()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, rng5 As Range, rng6 As Range, rng7 As Range, rng8 As Range Dim datenum As Long, Row As Integer, sorteddate As Variant, loc As Integer

Row = 2

And there are no >>> after rng5 As

Comment: When you are using the code `If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value))` what worksheet is the `Cells(i, j)` intended to refer to? Pretty much all other [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) references have a parent worksheet but this one does not. Perhaps it is referencing hte wrong worksheet and every cell is considered empty.

Comment: If an item isn't found BinarySearch is returning a zero which you are using as a row number.  So you need to test if BinarySearch is returning zero before you use it as a row number.

Comment: Consider posting a redacted sample workbook to a public share and coming back to add a publicly shared link to the workbook to your question. There are a lot of worksheets and a lot of data that makes testing unwieldy. Of course, the sample workbook should be redacted to the point where it does not exhibit the rogue behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Jeeped on this line:

```
If Not (IsEmpty(Cells(i, j).Value)) Then
```

You should reference the sheet the Cells reference in referring to. Otherwise Excel defaults to the active sheet so if you toggle between sheets the reference won't work as intended.

Comment: Fixed that good catch, might have helped with bugs I was having but I still can't tell because the code still won't run.  I should add, if there is a syntax error, vba catches it and tells me, but once it runs syntax error free it exits right away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I figured it out or at least figured a workaround.  For some reason my code won't run when the active sheet is "Sheet1".  When I make the active sheet "MKT" it works for some reason.  Now there are still bugs with linear search returning zero as someone mentioned, although it shouldn't because the values it is searching through all are dates and I buffered all the initial strings with zeros, but that is a bug I can deal with.  Thanks for everyone's help,

Cameron